# Poor performance of VNC client with compiz enabled on remote machine

Tags: 10.10, compiz, vnc

I am running a ubuntu 10.10 machine which is controlled remotely via the vinagre client installed on another machine running the same OS. The problem is that there is a significant delay in pointer movements when the remote machine has compiz enabled. However using metacity things are very smooth. Is it a problem with compiz, vinagre or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue with VNC protocol and Compiz. Most recommendations for this are to [add a button to switch between Metacity and Compiz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2352/vnc-remote-doesnt-work-with-ubuntu/2359#2359). You may also be interested in the [list of best VNC Clients](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4467/best-vnc-client-for-remote-desktop-assistance) for trying alternatives.

Comment: Ive heard somewhere that remmina is going to be the default on natty. If this is the case then i am definitely going to try that one.

Comment: remmina is a much better alternative to vinagre as far as performance under compiz is concerned. Thanks for the answer.